# Android app for walking and running for exercise

Tags: android, fitness

I am looking for an Android app, preferably gratis, but I could pay for something exceptional. I have preference for something F-Droid, or, at least, something that doesn't send my data to some large company (e.g, not Map my walk or Map my run).

Must have:

- measure speed, time and distance  covered
- calculate calories burned, based on gender, height & weight

Nice to have:

- history
- comparison/trends
- show map  / plan route, give directions
- export route data to a standard G.I.S format  (with timestamps, possibly other data)
- works with Garmin ForeRunner (at least for heart-rate, all else a bonus)

Any other features welcome

Comment: Not using any such app, hence no answer – just the usual question: have you already checked with [my corresponding list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_fitness)? RunnerUp might come close (but seems to lack calories); FitoTrack (see Fiximan's answer) should fit the bill and even exceed it.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use [FitoTrack](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.tadris.fitness/) which seems to come pretty close to your requirements:

- record speed, time, distance and altitude (would not trust that too much!)
- including history
- map (also historical), would not know of navigation, though
- export tracks to GPX-format (should include timestamps, too)
- calorie counter (by weight & type of sports)
- open source, no data collecting, OSM maps
- available via F-Droid

**NOT** featured: specifying sex and height, heart rate (AFAIK), offline maps (AFAIK)